# Grant select, update, delete and insert permission to particular tables only in single query

Tags: sql, rdbms

I have 50/60 tables in database and i want to grant select, update, delete, insert permission to particular tables only like granting access to 20 tables at a time. How to do it? I want to grant those 4 permission to my 20 tables at a time  in a single query

Ps: I can give access to individuals table but multiple tables at  a time `Grant insert, update, delete, select ON <table_name> TO All_roles`
But i want to give these permission to multiple tables

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using - as the answer is likely to be DBMS-specific. However, it is highly likely that you have to grant permissions to each table individually - unless all the tables are in one schema/database and they are the only tables in that schema/database

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i need different permission for different table like i need all 4 of permission to 6/7 tables and only one or two of them for other tables

Comment: The comments ask you to add a Tag mentioning the name of the `DBMS` you are using because otherwise there can be no real Answers, just guesses